# Startup bean is loading after calling Produces

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0

I have a two module in my application in which first module have a singleton startup bean where i bind my local service as a JNDI resource. In second module i have a Producer where i want to lookup this resource but getting a problem in whole life cycle as Produces is start invoke before the startup Bean and result is failed to load resource. Here is my code:

```
@Slf4j
@Singleton
@Startup
public class WebSocketServerActivator {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSocketServerActivator.class);

    private void startServer() {
        try {
            WebSocketServer webSocketServer = WebSocketServer.getInstance();
            webSocketServer.setHost("localhost");
            webSocketServer.setPort(9900);
            webSocketServer.initialize();

            InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
            ic.rebind(WebSocketSQLService.WEBSOCKET_SQL_JNDI, SQLRequestManager.getInstance());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Error while starting webSocket in start activator ", e);
        }
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        startServer();
    }

}
```

Here is a Producer class in other module:

```
public class WebSocketServiceLocator {

    @Produces
    public WebSocketSQLService getWebSocketService(
            @JndiStringResource(value = "visma.websocket.server", defaultValue = WebSocketSQLService.WEBSOCKET_SQL_JNDI)
                    Supplier<String> websocketServerName
    ) {
        return (WebSocketSQLService) lookupService(websocketServerName.get());
    }

    private Object lookupService(String lookupName) {
        try {
            InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
            return ic.lookup(lookupName);
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot find " + lookupName, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me why @startup bean loading after a WebSocketServiceLocator ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the tag you are using ejb-3.0 which does not provide @Startup yet.
If you are using 3.1 perhaps you can make both @Startup Singletons and use @DependsOn to define the sequence of the beans.
[see](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipvi.html)

Comment: Do you know how the @DependsOn can be apply when both of the EJB are in different module?

Comment: The Module should not be an issue, should be the EJB-Name. @Singleton(name = "Something")

Comment: Well actually it creating a problem i have anothre singleton EJB(TestSingleton) which activating before a WebSocketServerActivator EJB. I try to use a @DependsOn("WebSocketServerActivator") on TestSingleton and getting following error :
java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid DependsOn dependency 'WebSocketServerActivator' for EJB TestSingleton. Both of them are in separate module.

Comment: I had never this problem, so I can only write down, how I would proceed.
Is it a "Naming Problem"? I would look what the names are, after the deployment without DependsOn, so the deployment can work. And use that name.
 Is it a multiple module problem with unclear dependencies? I would try to fix these by avoiding circles. 
Is it a common multiple module problem? I would try to confince maven, to put everything into one module. 
Perhaps further google/search for EAR + DependsOn can help as well.

Comment: Combine these EJB in same module solve the issue. Thanks :)